# Disable Code Spellchecking in IntelliJ IDEA Across All Projects

Tags: intellij-idea, spell-checking

IntelliJ IDEA features the ability to perform spell checking of source code, and this checking can be toggled on and off separately for comments, literals, and the source code itself.  The setting is stored **per-project** however.

Is there a way to turn off spell checking of source code but **not comments and literals** across **all** projects?  Adjusting this setting for every project I create is tedious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The setting is stored per inspection profile, you can create your own profile in `File` | `Settings` | `Other Settings` | `Template Project Settings` | `Inspections`, all the new projects will have this profile by default, in the old projects you can change inspections profile to the new profile.